# Where to place min cardinality in an ER diagram

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship, cardinality

I am reading the book [Database Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133058352), 14th Edition. In chapter 5, Min and Max Cardinality are discussed. My question is mainly focused on min cardinality. For example, it is mentioned that a department has one or more employees while employee belongs to 0 or more department. The figure is as follows:

[image]

I have drawn the following diagram to understand how to place the oval and vertical bar for min, and the N and 1 for max cardinality

[image]

It seems to me both min and max cardinalities are reversed in the figure provided by the book. If an employee may not belong to a department, why oval is placed next to department? Similar question goes for max cardinality

I would deeply appreciate if someone could help me understand and further recommend detailed tutorials as the explanation in the book is not sufficient for me to understand. Note that I have read other tutorials, book, etc that use different notations, but I need to learn the notation from the above book.

Comment: There are multiple ways of drawing cardinalities in diagrams. Your book's drawing doesn't seem to follow any particular standard: looks like a cross between Chen and Crow's Foot. I tend to prefer the "Crow's Foot" notation, but that's just me. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–relationship_model#Cardinalities

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately, I do not have a choice of different notations, and I need to learn and apply the above notation only.